# Cordova app fails again on linking after updating to cordova 3.4.1 iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

When trying to build my app for archiving and updating to cordova 3.4.1 I get this linking error message. I solved something similar before but I am afraid to touch the build settings because x86_64 does not seem to be a supported architecture.

What can I do?

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/bogdan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Eazybreak-ctqyotqyclrvjoghewxpdeoemnkd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/bogdan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Eazybreak-ctqyotqyclrvjoghewxpdeoemnkd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CDVLocalNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_CDVPageDidLoadNotification", referenced from:

This is the error message I get (it's much longer of course).

Any help is appreciated.

Bogdan

Added full error log:

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/bogdan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Eazybreak-ctqyotqyclrvjoghewxpdeoemnkd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/bogdan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Eazybreak-ctqyotqyclrvjoghewxpdeoemnkd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CDVLocalNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_CDVPageDidLoadNotification", referenced from:
      -[CDVSplashScreen pluginInitialize] in CDVSplashScreen.o
  "_CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:handleOpenURL:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVDevice in CDVDevice.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVConnection in CDVConnection.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVNotification in CDVNotification.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVSplashScreen in CDVSplashScreen.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPluginResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVDevice.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVConnection.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVNotification.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in CDVDevice.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVDevice in CDVDevice.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVConnection in CDVConnection.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVNotification in CDVNotification.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVSplashScreen in CDVSplashScreen.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing x86_64 from Build Settings > Valid Architectures. I had a similar problem with arm64 architecture.